# Microsoft release manager taking second last version for deployment

Tags: tfs, ms-release-management

I am using Microsoft Release Management for Visual Studio 2013 Update 2.

I have setup deployer using ReleaseTfvcTemplate.12 template. This setup is deploying the code as expected but only problem I am seeing is it is not taking latest version. It is taking previous version of build for deployment.

Can anyone provide inputs on how can I resolve this?

Comment: That seems unlikely, as one of the parameters required to kick off the release via the ReleaseTfvcTemplate is the build number. The template will automatically pass in the build number. You'll have to provide a lot more detail in order to get any help. Also, I'd strongly recommend at least upgrading to 2013 Update 4, as each one of the 2013 updates provided significant bugfixes and improvements.

Comment: Did you get any error or related log info? How did you make sure it is not taking latest version? One possibility is after the release template finished, another related build triggered, then it looks like microsoft release manager taking second last version for deployment.

Comment: Thank you Patrick and Daniel for your inputs. I have upgraded to 2013 update 4 but still i am seeing same issue. i can see in the logs that template is sending correct build number in parameter. also it is showing correct build number in release management but it is taking MSI from previous build folder. (Example - it is taking MSI from 20160906.1 folder for release triggered from build 20160906.2)

Comment: Another observation here is Release is starting even before build is completed. that is why it is taking older build for deployment. is there anyway i can make sure release will start only after build completion or can i add some delay between build and deployment to make sure it takes latest build.

Answer (score 0):

First, please make sure your template created without any problem. Do not use the web downloaded version. You can follow below ways to create it:

When you install Release Management it creates a Build Template for you to use with an example**Release Management Build Process Template**. Release Management Build Process Templates are not installed in TFS by default, so it won’t appear as an available build process template until you add it.

Find the Template in your server install in : C:\Program Files (x86)\ Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\ReleaseManagement\bin\

```
TFS 2013 : ReleaseTfvcTemplate.12.xaml (or ReleaseGitTemplate.12.xaml if using GIT)
```

To add the release management build process template, you will need to check it in to your TFS source control in the BuildProcessTemplate folder in your project. Then add the build process file when editing (or adding) a Build Definition. Please ensure you use the above templates from the Release Management Server and not the client directory.

You can also update your VS2013 to the latest version just as *Daniel* suggests to see whether the issue still exist.